# WPF Listbox Group by Object Type

Tags: wpf, object, types, listbox, grouping

I have a listbox that binds to an ObservableCollection Property on a ViewModel.  The ObservableCollection is filled with objects of different Types.

I then use different DataTemplates to draw the ListboxItems differently depending on their Type.

I'd like to add some grouping so that I can put a header into the Listbox for each group of objects based on their Type.  I'm comfortable using a CollectionViewSource for such things but am not sure how to base the grouping on the object's Type.

Anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although you can't use a `PropertyGroupDescriptor` since there is no property for Type, you could still create a group descriptor that does the job.  Implement the abstract [`GroupDescription`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.groupdescription_methods%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class, and have it group using `GetType()`:

```
public class TypeGroupDescription : GroupDescription
{
    public override object GroupNameFromItem(object item, int level, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (item == null)
            return "";
        return item.GetType().Name;
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked a charm - cheers.  I just had to override the method.